# Database: best way to *flag a specific link* within a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, many-to-many, associative-table

Take for example a classical student and teacher many-to-many relationship:

```
Table "student": id, name
Table "teacher": id, name
Table "student_teacher": id, student_id, teacher_id, relation_quality
```

I need to add the concept that a student has a "referent teacher": in other words, to "flag" one relation with teachers as specific, for every student.

I see three possible methods:

1. add a one-to-many relation between teacher and students
2. add one-to-one relationship between student and student_teacher
3. add field "is_referent" to "student_teacher", setting it to True when appropriate

- With option 1, the link table `student_teacher` is "bypassed", which in my case would require some 'constraint' against setting a teacher as referent without any relation between student and teacher through the many-to-many path. Generating SQL queries to get the corresponding "relation_quality" does not appear too hard (we would have the two required FKs at hand), but I am not sure that it would not complicate my existing Django templates;
- With option 2 (which I am currently using), the 'constraint' to ensure is again that a student cannot connect to a 'referent' through an entry of the link table to which she/he is not related (i.e. a link used for another student). Maybe more importantly, it "looks more complex" within the relations diagram than the other options... By contrast, getting from student to either referent.relation_quality or the list of all its teacher is straightforward.
- With option 3, the logical integrity could also be compromised by setting more than one "is_referent" to True for a student... and as with option 1, I suspect that my very simple existing Django templates would need some new code to process this.

My impression is that both 3 approaches would work. But is one of these more advisable / standard, especially to avoid confusing people that might have to deal with my database in the future?

Comment: If your DBMS allows nulls in unique keys then I would go for option 3 and put a unique key on student_id + is_referent. If you set is_referent = Y for the one record and all others null then the unique key ensures that this can only be set one per student . N.b. Please tag your question with your DBMS

Comment: Thanks, I am not experienced with this "possible use of null keys", but guess I could try through the ORM with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/constraints/#uniqueconstraint A first quick check suggests that it is allowed.

Comment: Solution 3 is indeed appealing because it appears simple and because, as @NickW wrote, it is possible to set a constraint that is managed by the RDBMS. However, using this configuration is either more cumbersome or... beyond my experience. Using it trough SQL would seems fine, but using it through Django's ORM appeared more complex. I have things like "provide a list of students ordered by age of the referent teacher". Easy with solution 2, but with solution 3, how could the ORM get there easily?